# How can I correct the error "Cross-thread operation not valid"?

Tags: multithreading

This following code gives me the error below . I think I need "InvokeRequired" . But I don't understand how can I use?

error:Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'statusBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

the code :

```
 public void CalculateGeneration(int nPopulation, int nGeneration)

    {

        int _previousFitness = 0;
        Population TestPopulation = new Population();

        for (int i = 0; i < nGeneration; i++)
        {
            if (_threadFlag)
                break;
            TestPopulation.NextGeneration();
            Genome g = TestPopulation.GetHighestScoreGenome();

            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generation #{0}", i);
                if (  ToPercent(g.CurrentFitness) != _previousFitness)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
                    _gene = g;

                    statusBar1.Text = String.Format("Current Fitness = {0}",                g.CurrentFitness.ToString("0.00"));
                    this.Text = String.Format("Sudoko Grid - Generation {0}", i);
                    Invalidate();
                    _previousFitness = ToPercent(g.CurrentFitness);
                }

                if (g.CurrentFitness > .9999)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Final Solution at Generation {0}", i);
                    statusBar1.Text = "Finished";
                    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }


        } 


    }
```

Comment: Don't modify `statusBar1` from this thread. Ask the thread that created it to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest for reusability is to add a helper function like:

```
    void setstatus(string txt)
    {
        Action set = () => statusBar1.Text = txt; 
        statusBar1.Invoke(set);
    }
```

Or with the invokerequired check first:

```
    delegate void settextdelegate(string txt);
    void setstatus(string txt)
    {
        if (statusBar1.InvokeRequired)
            statusBar1.Invoke(new settextdelegate(setstatus), txt);
        else
            statusBar1.Text = txt;             
    }
```

Either way the status can then be set like

```
 setstatus("Finished");
```

For completeness I should add that even better would be to keep your calculating logic separated from your form and raise a status from within your calculating functionality that can be hanled by the form, but that could be completely out of scope here.

Comment: As a side note, not really applicable here, but I couldn't resist mentioning it: it just so happens that I blogged about an alternative to invoke yesterday. Just in case anyone wants to use a  separate controller/view architecture while safely posting events to the main thread. http://blog.subrosoftware.nl/?p=42 (nothing new mind you, just relatively unknown that it's right there in the framework)